# How to Calculate Percent of Sample mean falls within Population Mean?

Tags: distributions, intuition

Following screenshot is from Udacity Statistics Tutorial. Klout score which is  Social Media popularity score  is distributed as shown in picture.

Population mean is 37.72 and Standard Deviation is 16.04.Sample size is 35 and standard error is 2.71. Mean of the sample of the user(also n=35) who use bieber tweeter app is 40.

The video said 95 % of sample means fall within 2θ/√n (2xStandard Error) of the population mean. [image]What I understand is 95 % of sample means fall within 2 Standard Error on the sampling mean (sampling distribution) and how could it falls on population mean with same ratio while Standard Error is 2.71 and Standard Deviation is 16.04.

Please explain me.